# Is there a way to set message headers from a bean?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a simple camel route I need to modify. The route looks like this:

```
from(source.uri)
    .unmarshal()
    .bean(TransformMessageBean.class, "SomeMethod")
    .to(destination.uri)
```

I want to add another bean method call after the unmarshaling that set's a header value without disrupting the current data flow . Does anyone know of a way to do this? I read that in apache's documentation that a bean's return value is set in the outbound message body. Is there a way to change that to a header?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Certainly! One of the options available is

```
.setHeader("headerName").method(beanInstance, "methodToGetHeaderValue")
```

Using this approach, the method (say, `methodToGetHeaderValue`) on the provided bean instance will return a value, and that will become the value of the header.

There are a number of options available. You can call it [with a bean instance](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/ExpressionClause.html#method(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)), [a bean class](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/ExpressionClause.html#method(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) (like in your example), or even [a bean name](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/ExpressionClause.html#method(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), all with or without a method name.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the answer! Do you know the syntax for the above in xml? Is it something like this?

    <setHeader headerName="theHeader">

        <bean id="beanId" ref="MyBean" method="BeanMethod"/>      

    </setHeader>

Comment: Sorry, I can't say--I've mainly used the Java DSL

Answer (score 6):

In Spring XML DSL, it would be something like

```
 <setHeader headerName="headerName">
      <method bean="mybean" method="mymethod" />                
</setHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Another way in XML:

```
<setHeader name="headerName"> 
    <simple>${bean:yourBean.getMethod}</simple>           
</setHeader>
```