# How to set Header value as Bean method in Camel

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I'm setting header value as bean like this , but not working.

```
.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+authCache.getAuthCache().getClintToken());
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26920427/7717350

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to add a method on your `RouteBuilder` class where you define the route where you build that constant value.

```
public String clientToken() {
   return "Basic " + authCache.getAuthCache().getClientToken();
}
```

And then call this method from your Camel route

```
setHeader("Authorization", method(this, "clientToken"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.setHeader("Authorization", constant("Basic "+authCache.getAuthCache().getClientToken()));
```

Try this

Comment: That will only work if that client token should be set only once and be the same forever. If it must be per message then you need to use a Camel method call to call the method for each message.